# curl cookie jar file value

Tags: curl, cookies, libcurl

the output from curl -c file read as follow

`#HttpOnly_.mysite.net  TRUE    /   TRUE    0   mywebsessionid   000000-90ae-4ba5-b5be-4d10be6be098`

`#HttpOnly_.mysite.net  TRUE    /   TRUE    0   mysitepkey    0000_gv-X8nOvg9KgMLNWA==`

because of both value true I am getting "unauthorized" when I have edit manually "TRUE /FALSE" I am getting 200. what is may be the reason for TRUE/TRUE.

1st= command

```
 curl -c cookie.txt -d "username=user" -d "password=pass" https://www.example.com/login
```

2nd= command

```
 curl -b cookie.txt -v -X GET http://mysite/data/myfile/view -H "Content-type: application/json"
```

htttp header output

```
               > "Content-type: application/json"
               *   Trying 168.14.61.148...
               * Connected to login.mysite.come (168.14.61.148) port 8080                (#0)
             > GET /login.mysite.com HTTP/1.1
             > User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
              > Host: mysite.com:8080
             > Accept: */*
             > Cookie: mykey=ehhf3GYqNbIz5rMixfT1Pg22;
              > X-MYSITE-SESSION:323158ce-da52-41b8-9c66-a897fcb22222;
              > Content-type: application/json
               >
              < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
               < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
              < Content-Type: application/xml
              < Date: Sun, 27 Sep 2015 22:05:25 GMT
              < Expires: 0
               < Pragma: no-cache
              < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
             < Vary: Accept-Encoding
             < transfer-encoding: chunked
              < Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Show us the HTTP response headers when the cookies are received!

Comment: thanks Daniel, I have added the http header output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first TRUE, in the second column is "tailmatch" yes or no.

The second TRUE, in the forth column is "secure" cookie yes or no. A secure cookie is only ever sent over HTTPS.